# как сделать поиск по условию в текущей модели(таблице) и по условию в связанной? Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
Т.е есть таблица 

Batches
id,
name,
sales,
additional_sales(Данные подтягиваются из таблицы sales)

связанная таблица sales
id
Batch_id
add_sales

//Вот так получаю только если есть Искомое значение $value в связанная таблице sales
$batches = Batch::whereHas('sales', function ($query)use ($value) {
            $query->where('add_sales', 'like', '%'. $value .'%');
        })->paginate(10);

вот так в таблице основной Batches 
$batches = Batch::where('add_sales', 'like', '%'. $value .'%')->paginate(10);

Вопрос как получить все Batches у которых встречается Искомое значение $value либо в поле sales либо в add_sales ?

Спасибо!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Batch::where('add_sales', 'like', '%'. $value .'%')
      ->orWhereHas('sales', function ($query)use ($value) {
            $query->where('add_sales', 'like', '%'. $value .'%');
        })->paginate(10);
```

Как-то так.

Comment: спасибо я как раз сам решил так само)

Answer (score 0):

```php
$batches = Batch::where('sales', 'like', '%'. $value .'%')
  ->orWhereHas('aditional_sales', function ($query)use ($value) {
    $query->where('sale', 'like', '%'. $value .'%');
  })->paginate(10);
```